Review my 8-step sequencer

All pots are B10k.
Any issue with my circuit?
Something I should change?

You might [edit] to explain how you expect it to work, what the controls are and what the output is supposed to be.

you could possibly replace  CD40106 and CD4070 with 74HCS86. as this is a 5V part you would need to change supply voltage on U2 also.

A couple comments, without looking too closely at functionality:-
Assuming the 9V battery is a non-rechargeable type, you might want to add another 1N5817 to keep the adapter input from passing significant current through the battery.  A diode 'OR'.
Seems like you might want to buffer CVOUT so the pot source resistance (0 to 2.5kΩ) and the analog switch resistance (typically around 500Ω) does not affect the 'glide' timing. Also you might want to use RRIO op-amps rather than LM358 since the inputs can go higher than 3V.
U5.1 is abused a bit when the pot is turned down. You might want to add a series resistor and consider using a higher resistance pot and a smaller capacitor if you need more than ~10:1 range.
The CMOS ST oscillator and electrolytic capacitor timing is not going to be very predictable, especially worst-case. A 555 would be better. The limits for hysteresis at 25°C are 0.3V minimum 1.6V maximum, more than a 5:1 range. Typically they're much more consistent, but..

is this looks better? https://imgur.com/Ws70jK7 . The LM358 won't be able to buffer the output the can go between 0V to 5V ?

Yes, that addresses points 2 and 3. LM358 can accept inputs from GND to about 3V (3.5V typically under reference conditions) with a 5V supply. The output can drive a smallish current like 1mA from about +0.75V (sinking1mA) to about 3.7V (sourcing 1mA) with a 5V supply. Both the inputs and output need to be in range for a voltage follower to work properly. In contrast an inexpensive RRIO dual op-amp such as MCP6002 will typically swing within about 50mV of the rails sourcing or sinking 1mA, and the input range is not limiting.

What about taking out the opamp part as follow:https://imgur.com/a/y2ZS2it . The circuit should work using that 5V voltage regulator with those input and output caps of the regulator?

If the output is lightly loaded that might be okay, but I don't know your application. A 10kΩ load would reduce the output voltage by about 25%

output load usually is 100k
